# Как реализовать нормальный закон распределения

Tags: java

Мне нужно генерировать некоторое значение согласно некоторому распределению. В моем случае это нормальное распределение.
Есть ли в java что-то, что может в этом помочь? Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки, предназначенные под это?

Comment: > Центральная предельная теорема показывает, что в случае, когда результат измерения (наблюдения) складывается под действием многих независимых причин, причем каждая из них вносит лишь малый вклад, а совокупный итог определяется аддитивно, то есть путём сложения, то распределение результата измерения (наблюдения) близко к нормальному.

Конечно стандартный nextGaussian() из ответа лучше. Но мало ли пригодится. Можно генерить по несколько чисел любого распределения и считать их сумму (это будет одно из чисел нормальной последовательности).

Comment: это конечно так, так бы и делал, если бы не нашел баблиотек подходящих, но все-таки библиотеки есть, с ними проще..
Все-равно, спасибо!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nextGaussian()` из `java.util.Random`

Answer (score 0):

Есть простой алгоритм, разумеется, приближенный: среднее арифметическое 6 случайных с линейным распределением. В Java не силён, но в Processing.org, надстройке над Java, это выглядит примерно так:

```
float x = (random(1)+random(1)+random(1)+random(1)+random(1)+random(1)) / 6;
```

Меняя количество сэмплов можно получать более острую или размытую "шляпу" распределения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно самому реализовать. Возьмите интеграл от плотности вероятности: [image]

Теперь достаточно взять обычный rand (0, 1) и найти, какой x ему соответствует. Не знаю, есть ли обратная функция. В крайнем случае - бинарным поиском.

[Случайные величины. Нормальное распределение](http://www.toehelp.ru/theory/ter_ver/3_5/)

Comment: nextGaussian() и можно обойтись без очередного изобретения велосипеда)